# svg brightness/transparency effects and filters (Java Android)

Tags: java, android, svg

I'm using SVG files in my Game and i want to add transparency and brightness effects to them. So what i want is that a sprite becomes more and more transparent until it's invisible. This looks much smoother than a just disappearing sprite. This allows also smooth transitions between the levels where a white screen gets less transparent and then again more. I hope you understand what i mean. Besides this a brightness effect would be nice, too. A sprite can get brighter or darker during the game. Nevertheless i could create a workaround for this using the transparency effect, but yeah, i have none :/

I use this library:
https://androidsvg.googlecode.com/hg/doc/reference/packages.html

I render my svgs on this way:

```
svg.renderToCanvas(pCanvas);
```

However i can also convert it to pictures:

```
Picture pic = svg.renderToPicture();
```

Maybe this information will help you.

Does there exist something what could help me? And if not, have you an idea how can i solve the problem?

EDIT:So iwant my SVGs behave like these ones:
http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/24634091/

Comment: is then pic assigned to an ImageView? If so, you can set the alpha for that ImageView and let it become fully transparent in a loop

Comment: wait, whats an ImageView? So i have the MainActivity which creates my Gameview. GameView extends SurfaceView, so all i have to do is replace SurfaceView by ImageView? Okay thank you very much. I have at the moment no idea what to do more to get it work, but now i know at least that i have to google imageView, thanks! :)

btw how my acutal project works:
Activity sets in onCreate contentView to a new GameView. My GameView extends Surfaceview and creates a Thread and the Sprites in surfaceCreated. The Thread calls the onDraw of my GameView. This calls the onDraw of all the Sprites.

Comment: An ImageView is a control made to contain just an image (and, optionally, a background). It has the setAlpha method, as most Views (so, GameView should have it). If you do a loop that sets the Alpha progressively to 0, you'll get your disappearing effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an ImageView and setAlpha(), as Frank says.  Or it may just be easier to render the sprites to the canvas in your draw() method.

If you are writing a game, then you may find that rendering SVGs in your game loop may not be fast enough.  So you might have to pre-render all your SVG sprites to Bitmaps (ie on startup) and draw them to your Canvas.

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setAlpha(alpha);
canvas.drawBitmap(sprite, x,y, p);
```

Comment: okay thank you! It sounds good to pre-render them to bitmaps, i also tried to do this, but never found a solution. All i got was a SVG converted to a picture, but then i had still no way to render it together with a picture. I also found no working code to render SVG to Bitmap with the actual library. In past versions it was possible to get drawables using the SvgParser, but in the latest version nothing like this exists. Do you know any workaround to convert svgs to bmp?

Comment: There is an example of how to render SVGs to Bitmaps on the home page of the library.

Comment: Do you mean this one?

   `SVG  svg = SVG.getFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), filename);
   if (svg.getDocumentWidth() != -1) {
      Bitmap  newBM = Bitmap.createBitmap(Math.ceil(svg.getDocumentWidth()),
                                          Math.ceil(svg.getDocumentHeight()),
                                          Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
      Canvas  bmcanvas = new Canvas(newBM);
      svg.renderToCanvas(bmcanvas);
   }`
I don't see where i get there a bitmap, because newBM has just the size of the svg, but i do not get any bitmap for any other uses :(

Comment: That code draws the SVG into the Bitmap (newBM).  You can then do anything you want with that bitmap - like draw it onto the screen.